# Rviz Interactive marker does not move towards y-axis

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

recently I am playing around with my custom 5-dof robot. In Rviz MotionPlanning panel, I can add `<random valid>` Goal State to my Query and the corresponding motion can be planned and executed.

However, when I manually try to move the robot with the interactive marker, the marker simply does not move towards y-axis. I thought the marker is not moving because I commanded the robot to move to an unreachable position, however since the Query panel succeeded to bring the robot to that position, I am clueless.

What could be other reasons for this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358864/rviz-interactive-marker-does-not-move-towards-y-axis/) by [xman236](https://answers.ros.org/users/47615/xman236/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2020-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> when I manually try to move the robot with the interactive marker, the marker simply does not move towards y-axis.

The interactive marker, as used by the MoveIt RViz plugin, is a 6 DoF marker.

It's inherently impossible for a 5 DoF robot to reach all the poses a 6 DoF marker can assume.

That's the immediate cause of the behaviour you observe.

> I thought the marker is not moving because I commanded the robot to move to an unreachable position,

Indeed.

But note: you're not *commanding* anything yet. The marker *only* alters the Goal State.

> however since the Query panel succeeded to bring the robot to that position, I am clueless.

Using the `<random valid>` option from the dropdown instructs the MoveIt RViz plugin to chose a random *joint space pose* for the selected group.

As joint space poses will always be reachable -- no matter the nr of DoF -- this will work.

No IK is involved there, which would explain why you cannnot use the marker, but can set a random joint space pose successfully.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0